# Energy lost due to air drag of a varying velocity object

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, fluid-dynamics, energy-conservation, drag

How do we calculate total energy lost of an object due to air drag which is moving with varying velocity (from $v_1$ to $v_2$ m/s with an acceleration $a$ and over a displacement $s$) in air? Assume other parameters like drag coefficient - $C$, area of object facing air - $A$, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An infinitesimal amount of work is given by:
$$\text{d}W_{loss}=F_D\text{d}x\tag{1}$$
The drag force is given by:
$$F_D=\frac12 \rho A C_Dv^2\tag{2}$$
Now find a relation between $\text{d}x$ and $\text{d}v$:
$$v=\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t}=\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}v}\frac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}t}=a\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}v}$$
Because $\frac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}t}=a$
$$\Rightarrow \text{d}x=\frac{1}{a}v\text{d}v\tag{3}$$
$$\text{d}W_{loss}=\frac{1}{2a} \rho A C_Dv^3\text{d}v$$
Integrate this between $v_1$ and $v_2$.