# Approximating energy loss in double pendulum due to drag

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, drag

I'm trying to approximate energy loss due to drag in a double pendulum system using the Lagrangian. The idea being to come up with an equation of the work done $(W)$ on the masses due to drag and append it to the Lagrangian.
$$\mathcal{L}=(T-W)-V$$

I know there maybe some false assumptions, but I'm moreso struggling with the math here. The coordinate system I'm using is the following:

[image]

We have the drag equation $F_d = \frac{1}{2}\rho v^2C_D A$ and since work done by variable force is given by $W= \int^{s_2}_{s_1}F(s)\ ds$ where $s$ is displacement, we arrive at the equation.

$$
    W =\ \int^{s_2}_{s_1}\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2C_D A\ ds = \frac{1}{2}\rho C_D A\int^{s_2}_{s_1} v^2 \ ds$$

but I'm not quite sure how does one perform change of variables to the integral. Consider the first mass $m_1$. We know that
$\dot{x_1}=l_1\dot{\theta}\cos\theta_1$ and $\dot{y_1}=-l_1\dot{\theta}\sin\theta_1$, so the total velocity is simply $v_1=\sqrt{\dot{x_1}^2+\dot{y_1}^2}$ which works out to be $v_1=l_1\dot{\theta_1}$, so we get that the work done on the first mass by drag is

$$W_1=\frac{1}{2}\rho C_D A\int^{s_2}_{s_1} (l_1\dot{\theta_1})^2 \ ds$$

The issue still remains, since $\theta$ and $\dot{\theta}$ is ultimately a function of time, do I have to change $ds$ into $dt$ somehow? ultimately, I would like to derive something in terms of $\theta$ or $\dot{\theta}$ (so in terms of $t$ I suppose$) so I can obtain the equations of motion, and subsequently perform numerical analysis.

EDIT: Just clarifying the goal I suppose: is to get something like
$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}(m_1+m_2)l^2_1\dot{\theta_1}^2+\frac{1}{2}m_2l_2^2\dot{\theta_2^2}+m_1l_1l_2\dot{\theta_1}\dot{\theta_2}\cos{(\theta_1-\theta_2)}-\mathbf{W(\theta_1)}-\mathbf{W(\theta_2)}+(m_1+m_2)l_1g\cos{\theta_1}+m_2gl_2\cos\theta_2$$

where $\mathbf{W(\theta_1)}$ and $\mathbf{W(\theta_2)}$ is the work done by drag on mass 1 and 2.

EDIT2: I found this thread https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/607449/292833 which provided the derivation
$$\text{d}W_{loss}=\frac{1}{2a} \rho A C_Dv^3\text{d}v$$
since $v_1=l_1\dot{\theta_1}$, we have $dv_1 = l_1\ddot{\theta_1}d \dot{\theta}$, since $a_1=l_1\ddot{\theta_1}$, we now have
$$\text{d}W_{loss}=\frac{1}{2l_1\ddot{\theta_1}} \rho A C_D\dot{\theta}^3l_1\ddot{\theta_1}\text{d}\dot{\theta}$$
$$W_{loss} = \int^{l_1\dot{\theta_{1f}}}_{l_1\dot{\theta_{1i}}} \frac{1}{2} \rho AC_D\dot{\theta}^3\text{d}\dot{\theta}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Does not look quite correct. It should be $dv_1=l_1\,d\dot\theta_1$ and therefore $dW_{loss}=\frac{1}{2l_1\ddot\theta_1}\rho AC_D\,l_1^4\,\dot\theta^3_1\,d\dot\theta_1=\frac{1}{2}\rho A C_D\,l_1^3\,\dot\theta^3_1\,dt\,.$ If you don't know the function $\dot\theta_1(t)$ this does not seem to be solvable any further.

Comment: $\begin{aligned}\text{you should use those equations }\\W=\int \overrightarrow{F}\cdot d\overrightarrow{r}\\
\overrightarrow{r}=\overrightarrow{r}\left( \varphi \right) \\
\overrightarrow{F}=\dfrac{1}{2}\rho\,C_{D}A\overrightarrow{v}\cdot \overrightarrow{v}\begin{pmatrix}
\sin\left( \varphi \right)  \\
\cos \left( \varphi \right) 
\end{pmatrix}\end{aligned}$